# NetworkOperator name for both simcard in 5.0.2 device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, telephony

I want to know operator name for both sim card.I do it but It is not working in 5.0.2 device.

**Here is my code:**

```
 operator1 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(getApplicationContext(),
            "getNetworkOperatorName", 0);
 operator2 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(getApplicationContext(),
            "getNetworkOperatorName", 1);
```

**TelePhonyInfo:**

```
public final class TelephonyInfo {

private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
String optName1, optName2, imsiSIM1, imsiSIM2;
private boolean isSIM1Ready;
private boolean isSIM2Ready;
private boolean isSIM1Activated;
private boolean isSIM2Activated;

public boolean isSIM1Activated() {
    return isSIM1Activated;
}

public void setSIM1Activated(boolean isSIM1Activated) {
    this.isSIM1Activated = isSIM1Activated;
}

public boolean isSIM2Activated() {
    return isSIM2Activated;
}

public void setSIM2Activated(boolean isSIM2Activated) {
    this.isSIM2Activated = isSIM2Activated;
}

public String getImsiSIM1() {
    return imsiSIM1;
}

public String getImsiSIM2() {
    return imsiSIM2;
}

public String getoptName1() {
    return imsiSIM2;
}

public String getoptName2() {
    return imsiSIM2;
}

public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
    return isSIM1Ready;
}

public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
    return isSIM2Ready;
}

public boolean isDualSIM() {
    return imsiSIM2 != null;
}

private TelephonyInfo() {
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context) {

    if (telephonyInfo == null) {

        telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = null;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                    "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                    "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                        "getDeviceId", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                        "getDeviceId", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                // Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name
                // if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        telephonyInfo.optName1 = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
        telephonyInfo.optName2 = null;

        telephonyInfo.optName1 = getOutput(context,
                "getNetworkOperatorNameGemini", 0);
        telephonyInfo.optName2 = getOutput(context,
                "getNetworkOperatorNameGemini", 1);

        Log.d("tagKrishna1234", "not go in this condition");
        telephonyInfo.optName1 = getOutput(context,
                "getNetworkOperatorName", 0);
        telephonyInfo.optName2 = getOutput(context,
                "getNetworkOperatorName", 1);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 21) {

            Log.d("tagKrishna1234", "go in this condition");
            telephonyInfo.optName1 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(context,
                    "getNetworkOperator", 0);
            telephonyInfo.optName1 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(context,
                    "getNetworkOperator", 1);

        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

            telephonyInfo.optName1 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(context,
                    "getNetworkOperatorName", 1);
            telephonyInfo.optName2 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(context,
                    "getNetworkOperatorName", 2);

        }

        telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT;
        telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = false;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                    "getSimStateGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                    "getSimStateGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e2) {

            e2.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimState", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimState", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                // Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name
                // if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
        telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                    "getSimStateGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                    "getSimStateGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimState", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimState", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                // Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name
                // if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT;
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = false;

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimStateGemini", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(context,
                        "getSimStateGemini", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM1Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(
                            context, "getSimState", 0);
                    telephonyInfo.isSIM2Activated = getSIMStateBySlot(
                            context, "getSimState", 1);
                } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method
                    // name
                    // if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return telephonyInfo;

}

public static String getOutput(Context context, String methodName,
        int slotId) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    String reflectionMethod = null;
    String output = null;
    try {
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        for (Method method : telephonyClass.getMethods()) {
            String name = method.getName();
            if (name.contains(methodName)) {
                Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1 && params[0].getName().equals("int")) {
                    reflectionMethod = name;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (reflectionMethod != null) {
        try {
            output = getOpByReflection(telephony, reflectionMethod, slotId,
                    false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return output;
}

private static String getOpByReflection(TelephonyManager telephony,
        String predictedMethodName, int slotID, boolean isPrivate) {

    // Log.i("Reflection", "Method: " + predictedMethodName+" "+slotID);
    String result = null;

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass()
                .getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID;
        if (slotID != -1) {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                        predictedMethodName, parameter);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName,
                        parameter);
            }
        } else {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass
                        .getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName);
            }
        }

        Object ob_phone;
        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        if (getSimID != null) {
            if (slotID != -1) {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
            } else {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony);
            }

            if (ob_phone != null) {
                result = ob_phone.toString();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Log.i("Reflection", "Result: " + e.printStackTrace());
        return null;
    }

    return result;
}

public static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context,
        String predictedMethodName, int slotID)
        throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    String imsi = null;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass()
                .getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName,
                parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if (ob_phone != null) {
            imsi = ob_phone.toString();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return imsi;
}

public static String getNetworkOperator(Context context,
        String predictedMethodName, int slotID)
        throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    String Operator = null;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass()
                .getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSIMOperator = telephonyClass.getMethod(
                predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSIMOperator.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if (ob_phone != null) {
            Operator = ob_phone.toString();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return Operator;
}

private static boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context,
        String predictedMethodName, int slotID)
        throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    boolean isReady = false;
    boolean isActivated = false;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass()
                .getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(
                predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if (ob_phone != null) {
            int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
            if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
                isReady = true;
            } else if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
                isActivated = false;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return isReady;
}

private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

    public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
        super(info);
    }
}
}
```

Operator name return null in 5.0.2 In other API it return true operator name.
Thanks.